# Choosing monitor for gaming

Tags: graphics-cards, monitors

My PC is i5-6600K, Gigabyte G1 GTX1070, 16Gb RAM.

At the moment I use two monitors - Dell U2414H for gaming and coding and old Samsung BX2035 for Internet browsing.

I want to buy 144Hz monitor for games and right now Im choosing within Asus PG248Q, Asus PG279Q, Dell S2417DG, Dell S2716DG and AOC AGON AG271QG. Of course Asus PG279Q is the best, but I have to buy it from computeruniverse.com due to hight price in my country so this option has its drawbacks.

The new monitor should become the main one, and U2414H should be used for Internet surfing.

In general, I want to get advice on **which monitor is better in the described situation**, and also I have a few questions:

1. **Is TN really worse than IPS?** I always sit in a lighted room and look at the monitor straight so bleeding is not a problem.
2. **Is 1440p good for 24"?** Will not the text be too small? And if I increase the scale, will there be blurrs due to interpolation?
3. **Is 1440p 144Hz good with GTX1070?** And will it be good in the next 2-3 years?

Actually I rarely play in competitve FPS, **maybe I do not need 144Hz at all?** As an example of the games I play: World of Warcraft, Dota 2, Starcraft 2, Civilization 6, Fallout 4, Tomb Rider etc.

I will be glad to any advice or links to articles.

Comment: The problem with TN isn't bleeding, it's color shift.  For example, the top image on [this test page](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/viewing_angle.php) shows white stripes on a medium-grey background at the top of my TN monitor, and red stripes on a light-grey background at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** YES

**2.** I would recommend 1080p for 24" simply because you will get way more frames per second, and again more PPI, looks better and in this case 1440p with 24" is about 121PPI and 1440p with 27" is about 109PPI so really not much of a difference. Also I think I saw couple of 27" monitors and 2560x1440 at 27" is the same pixel density as 1920x1080 at 24"

**3.** It is and for 90% of upcoming games in next 3 years it will be, but then again don't hold my word, we can't predict future tough I reckon you will be able to play them in medium-high settings(in 3 years)

The monitors I would recommend are Dell S2417DG and Asus PG248Q tough I prefer Dell over Asus